# Can we make a DISTINCT of a group_concat(distinct somefield)?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, correlated-subquery

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37dd94/17

If I do `SELECT DISTINCT` I get the same results as doing just `SELECT`.

On the query results, you will see two activities that contains the District "Evora".
Only one should appear.

Any clue?

Comment: you are doing `GROUP BY t.name ` and it will group the data with respect to this and the district names will be concated per `t.name` so what is wrong with this ?

Comment: It's doing what you're asking it to. They are both distinct values based on the table. You are actually getting less results, so the distinct is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following query ([**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37dd94/41/0)):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(APA_T.district), t.name
FROM tbl_activity AS t 
JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap ON t.id = ap.id_activity 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT apa.district AS district, 
  (
     SELECT s1.id_activity_package 
     FROM tbl_activity_package_address s1
     WHERE apa.district = s1.district
     ORDER BY s1.id DESC
     LIMIT 1
  ) AS idActivityPackage
  FROM 
  tbl_activity_package_address apa
  ORDER BY apa.district
) AS APA_T
ON ap.id = APA_T.idActivityPackage
GROUP BY t.name 
ORDER BY APA_T.district;
```

The above query will eliminate the extra `Faro` and `Evora`.

Comment: the all point is to have either activity-1 or activity-3 listed. Since both have Evora. I shouldn't not have both. Only one of them should appear. That's the issue. Please advice.

Comment: Your question is **Any clue?***.  So in detail I explained why you were getting the results you were seeing.  Based on your query it should appear twice.

Comment: How would you determine which one should appear and which one shouldn't?  is one record bogus and simply need to be deleted?

Comment: @Linger, Why do you think it's not necessary to use the two inner joins?

Comment: @Linger - it could be the highest ID takes precedence.

Comment: **@felipe.zkn**, hey I don't know what I was thinking when I decided that.  I was wrong.  I corrected my answer.

Comment: That does reply to the question. Thanks. I've accept it. But to be honest, I now need to list all other records because they should NOT be disregarded, they should only appear at the bottom of our list. At the very end, perhaps the select query could be simpler, but the ORDER BY quite complex. Not sure if only MYSQL can pull this out. Sorry for not telling you this, but it's very hard to formulate all this on a single question.

Comment: That would actually complicate the query quite a bit more.  I wouldn't recommend it.  On a larger data set the query would run noticeably slower.  If you need them all anyway, why not just use your original query?

Comment: Thanks a lot Linger for being there. It's being a hard time. Well, it really gets crazy. :( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37dd94/51 - and you have to repeat a LOT, and activity-1 gets listed twice (and it sure does, because the UNION DISTINCT doesn't see any equality there perhaps). You asked why I don't use the original query, because the requirement would be that, the first listed records (on a given infinite scroll plugin), should have DISTINCT districts. So the first query doesn't solve that. :(

Comment: That's why I said it would be difficult.  The flaw in your query is you want my query plus the union of the opposite of my query.  That is a little difficult to write.  The way you have it is my query plus the union of the original query.  What you really want is `Beja,Evora,Faro,Setubal    Activity-1` to be `Evora activity-1`.  I would recommend asking another question?  It is more than just an easy alteration to my answer here.

Comment: I will give it a try on a new question. But I don't want `Evora activity-1`, on this last comment query result I want this `Beja,Evora,Faro,Setubal Activity-1` to disappear. Because we already have that activity covered on our results list.

Comment: Right but you don't have `Evora` under `activity-1`.  So really you just want `Faro` to be produced in the second query of the union since `activity-3` is not in the first query, correct?

Comment: I have `Evora` under `activity-1` - but on the "second" `activity-1` the one that appears from the second union select. `Faro` doesn't play a role on the question I guess. The point is: We want to list activities. Each activity may have different packages. Each package can have several districts. So, each activity can have several districts. On a infinite scroll view, it would be important, for the user, that he/she doesn't see the last 10 activities, because, they may be ALL from the same district. And the request is to show activities, at least on the first scroll "pages", that are from diff

Comment: erent, districts. So, we wish not to have the same activity listed twice to the user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550816/query-returning-one-extra-record-any-advice-on-how-to-remove-it-from-the-quer - So that we don't get too off-topic. :)